# Representation with, scale_fill_gradientn ggplot2, constant gradient

Tags: r, ggplot2, scale, gradient, polar-coordinates

I have the following code to create a polar plot with `ggplot2` but I am not be able to maintain the same scale color-values when I run the same code with other data.

There are 3 different variables to represent, one is the orientation:

```
plot.new()
ggplot(NS_Enero, aes(x = wd, y = ws, fill = manganese, size = manganese)) +
  coord_polar() +
  geom_point(shape = 21, show.legend = TRUE) +
  scale_size(range = c(3,12),
             labels = c("50", "150", "450", "1350", "4050"),
             breaks = c(50, 150, 450, 1350, 4050),
             name = expression(paste(PM[10]~bound~Mn~(ng/m^3)))) +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours = c("darkblue","blue", "yellow", "orange", "red"),
                       space = "Lab",
                       guide = "legend",
                       values = rescale(c(0, 150, 450, 1350, 4401),
                                        from = c(0, 4401)),
                       labels = c("50", "150", "450", "1350", "4050"),
                       breaks = c(50, 150, 450, 1350, 4050),
                       name = expression(paste(PM[10]~bound~Mn~(ng/m^3)))) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits= c(0,360),
                     breaks= c(0, 90, 180, 270), 
                     labels = c("N","E","S","W"),
                     name = "") +
  scale_y_continuous(name = "Distance (m)",
                     position = "left") +
  theme_linedraw() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 12),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 8)) +
  ggtitle("                 NS_Enero")
```

When I try to run the same code with different data the output plot change the values of the scale, I have tried a lot of tips that I found in other questions, but I can't solve the problem with the scale representation. I think that the problem is in the `values` from `scale_fill_gradientn`...

**Output 1:**

[image: Plot1]

**Output 2 (different data):**

[image: Plot 2]

The final result is ok but I want that the values of the scale range (size and color) to be constant in all the plots that I run with different range of data. The same values of size and color for values between 0 to 4050.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Maybe specify `limits` in `scale_fill_gradientn`?

Comment: Oh God, that was so simple, but it works, thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, adding `limits` it worked.

This is the final code:

```
#Tamaño y color
plot.new()
ggplot(NS_Junio, aes(x = wd, y = ws, fill = manganese, size = manganese)) +
  coord_polar() +
  geom_point(shape = 21, show.legend = TRUE) +
  scale_size(range = c(3,12),
             labels = c("50", "150", "450", "1350", "4050"),
             breaks = c(50, 150, 450, 1350, 4050),
             limits = c(1,4050),
             name = expression(paste(PM[10]~bound~Mn~(ng/m^3)))) +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours = c("darkblue","blue", "yellow", "orange", "red"),
                       space = "Lab",
                       guide = "legend",
                       values = rescale(c(0, 150, 450, 1350, 4401),
                                        from = c(0, 4401)),
                       labels = c("50", "150", "450", "1350", "4050"),
                       breaks = c(50, 150, 450, 1350, 4050),
                       limits = c(1,4050),
                       name = expression(paste(PM[10]~bound~Mn~(ng/m^3)))) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits= c(0,360),
                     breaks= c(0, 90, 180, 270), 
                     labels = c("N","E","S","W"),
                     name = "") +
  scale_y_continuous(name = "Distance (m)",
                     position = "left") +
  theme_linedraw() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 12),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 8)) +
  ggtitle("                 NS_Enero")
```